# How to merge values from different columns into one column without repeating the values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Right super geeks... here is the scenario that is making me feel suicidal!

I have got this query:

```
SELECT
BIRMINGHAM.TOS, 
BIRMINGHAM.Percentage, 
CARDIFFREGUS.TOS AS Expr1, 
CARDIFFREGUS.Percentage AS Expr2

FROM
BIRMINGHAM  RIGHT OUTER JOIN
CARDIFFREGUS ON BIRMINGHAM.TOS = CARDIFFREGUS.TOS
```

And this is the result I get:

> `TOS            Percentage    Expr1          Expr2
>                      100.00%                      100.00%
>                      0.07%                        100.00%
>   default (DSCP 0)   61.37%   default (DSCP 0)    61.74%
>   af33 (DSCP 30)     11.49%   af33 (DSCP 30)      15.44%
>   af31 (DSCP 26)     8.86%    af31 (DSCP 26)      13.85%
>   af11 (DSCP 10)     15.22%   af11 (DSCP 10)      4.63%
>   ef (DSCP 46)       1.91%    ef (DSCP 46)        3.72%
>   NULL               NULL     cs6 (DSCP 48)       0.23%
>   cs4 (DSCP 32)      0.15%    cs4 (DSCP 32)       0.20%
>   cs3 (DSCP 24)      0.06%    cs3 (DSCP 24)       0.11%
>   af21 (DSCP 18)     0.05%    af21 (DSCP 18)      0.05%
>   af41 (DSCP 34)     0.70%    af41 (DSCP 34)      0.03%
>                      100.00%                      0.02%
>                      0.07%                        0.02%`

As you can see some of the values of the TOS and Expr1 columns are the same.
the percentage and expr2 columns are the corresponding values of the TOS and expr1 columns respectively.

what i need is to display the values of the TOS and Expr1 columns as 1 column but all the values have to be there once (not repeat the same values) and then i need the values of the percentage and expr2 columns to display next to the "new" created column (TOS + Expr1) with their respective relationship to the original value of the TOS and expr1 column.

the percentage and expr2 colums need to reamin indipendent from each other.

Comment: For everybody's best, do `CARDIFFREGUS LEFT OUTER JOIN BIRMINGHAM` instead.

Comment: What if BIRMINGHAM.TOS is NULL? (But CARDIFFREGUS.TOS isn't.)

Comment: Please provide an example of the output that you're looking for.

Comment: then the value of cardiffregus.tos should appear on the new column

Comment: all the values are the same on both columns except for cs6 (DSCP 48) on the Expr1 column. so i need cs6 (DSCP 48) to appear on the new created column (TOS + Expr1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
COALESCE(BIRMINGHAM.TOS,CARDIFFREGUS.TOS) AS [NewColumn], 
BIRMINGHAM.Percentage,  
CARDIFFREGUS.Percentage AS Expr2

FROM
BIRMINGHAM  RIGHT OUTER JOIN
CARDIFFREGUS ON BIRMINGHAM.TOS = CARDIFFREGUS.TOS
```

EDIT:

Note that you will not be able to view records from CARDIFFREGUS which do not match the JOIN condition. If you would like to view such records too then use a FULL OUTER JOIN.

For more information on COALESCE(): [COALESCE MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190349.aspx)

I'm not sure what you mean by 'sites' in your comment. If you mean more tables, add another JOIN condition and include the NewTable.TOS column in the COALESCE function.

Comment: That was exactly what i was looking for! thanks!.... what if i want to add more sites?

Comment: You don't need that COALESCE, simply select CARDIFFREGUS.TOS only.

Comment: can you please eloborate a little bit more as your answer does not make sense to me?

Comment: @jarlh Yes, you are correct. However, I think it should be a FULL OUTER JOIN for what OP is trying to do. And COALESCE is needed for this case.